# Endless wait in Scala

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, akka

How to wait in Scala . I have a listener which is listening continuously if any event occurs. The `Listener` will process the events and needs to listen till the application shuts down.

In Java I achieve this by instantiating a new thread, starting the listener and putting it in "Wait" state.

```
Object o = new Object();
synchronized(o) { o.wait(); }
```

But when I do the same in Scala (creating a thread and putting it on wait), the `Listener` doesn't receive and doesn't process the events.

How can we achieve this in Scala?

I'm using snmp4j to listen and process the traps to manager.

Code Snippet:

```
def listen() {
  synchronized {
    val address = new UdpAddress("127.0.0.1/2221")
    val transport: DefaultUdpTransportMapping = new efaultUdpTransportMapping()
    val msDispatcher: MessageDispatcher = new MessageDispatcherImpl
  msDispatcher.addMessageProcessingModel(new MPv2c)

    SecurityProtocols.getInstance.addDefaultProtocols()
    SecurityProtocols.getInstance.addPrivacyProtocol(new Priv3DES)

    val target = new CommunityTarget()
    target.setCommunity(new OctetString("public"))

    val snmp: Snmp = new Snmp(msDispatcher, transport)
    snmp.addCommandResponder(this)
    println(" listening on ..." + snmpDevice.host)
    transport.listen()
    this.wait(1000 * 60)
  }
}

override def processPdu(cmdRespEvent: CommandResponderEvent): Unit = {
  synchronized {
    println("inside process pdu")
    val pdu: PDU = cmdRespEvent.getPDU()
    if (pdu != null) {
      println(" Trap Type = " + pdu.getType())
      println(" Variable Bindings = " + pdu.getVariableBindings())
      // int pduType = pdu.getType()
      if (pdu != null && pdu.getType() == PDU.INFORM) {
        // procees the event
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to add minimal code example that shows your problem, without that its very hard to to know why your getting this problem.

Comment: `val o = new Object
    synchronized(
      o.wait()
    )` would work the same. You need to show more code.

Comment: I've user this.wait() in listen method in java, was working and if any event occurs , processing also.

But in scala same is not responding

Comment: Your example is inappropriate. It does everything besedies synchronized wait-notify!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a wrapper for snmp4j would help, see if this would be an option: https://github.com/joescii/snmp4s

My humble opinion is that all that synchronized code in scala is not the way to go about it

Comment: Yes synchronized is bad. I want to continue listen till the application shutdown.How to achieve this in scala?
I've tried with Future and Promise .but bot working :(

Comment: I'd try that wrapper and see if it gives you the ability to get a Future and use callbacks, if it does you will avoid the pain to reinvent the wheel once more

Answer (score 0):

Look at these 2 methodologies:

1. Checking repetitively on a task to see if its finished then continue to the next task when it is done (blocking some thread).
2. After the 1st task has finished trigger an event which notifies the next task to complete (no blocking)

Number 1 is blocking a thread whilst 2 is not. This is the same as me doing a task and telling you to do your task when I'm finished, I don't let you know when I'm finish you have to keep checking yourself, or I could just tell you when I finish so you can keep going about any other business you have in the mean time.

But anyway you shouldn't be telling a listener to wait, that will stop the thread that is listening for the event. But even better than that is to not do that at all for the reasons I argued above. And I think you should be careful to not think that every listener is also a thread. This is not true! Because instead of listeners checking for an event, the event notifies the listener as I have explained.